# how to merge invalid xml files?

Tags: xml, merge

Original (older) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notes version="1">
    <labels>
        <label id="0" color="80FF80">BadReg</label>
        <label id="1" color="FFFF40">GoodReg</label>
        <label id="2" color="8000FF">Bluffer</label>
        <label id="3" color="10FF10">Fish</label>
        <label id="4" color="1080FF">Loose</label>
        <label id="5" color="30DBFF">Semi-Loose</label>
        <label id="6" color="FF">Nit</label>
        <label id="7" color="FF9F48">Tight</label>
        <label id="8" color="C0C0C0">Undefined</label>
    </labels>
    <note player="&quot;Seikei&quot;&amp;5RS" label="8" update="1429734930"></note>
    <note player="#23Mattingly" label="5" update="1429734930">Note1</note>
    <note player="#PachnacyBak" label="7" update="1429734930">Note2</note>
    <note player="$attlaz" label="3" update="1429734930">Note3</note>
</notes>
```

To merge with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notes version="1">
    <labels>
        <label id="0" color="80FF80">BadReg</label>
        <label id="1" color="FFFF40">GoodReg</label>
        <label id="2" color="8000FF">Bluffer</label>
        <label id="3" color="10FF10">Fish</label>
        <label id="4" color="1080FF">Loose</label>
        <label id="5" color="30DBFF">Semi-Loose</label>
        <label id="6" color="0000FF">Nit</label>
        <label id="7" color="FF9F48">Tight</label>
        <label id="8" color="C0C0C0">Undefined</label>
    </labels>
    <note player="&quot;Seikei&quot;&amp;5RS" label="8" update="1429734930"></note>
    <note player="#23Mattingly" label="5" update="1429734930"></note>
    <note player="#PachnacyBak" label="7" update="1429734930"></note>
    <note player="$attlaz" label="2" update="1429734930"></note>
    <note player="111kakarot" label="1" update="1429734930"></note>
    <note player="111PO111" label="2" update="1429734930"></note>
</notes>
```

Output I wish to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notes version="1">
    <labels>
        <label id="0" color="80FF80">BadReg</label>
        <label id="1" color="FFFF40">GoodReg</label>
        <label id="2" color="8000FF">Bluffer</label>
        <label id="3" color="10FF10">Fish</label>
        <label id="4" color="1080FF">Loose</label>
        <label id="5" color="30DBFF">Semi-Loose</label>
        <label id="6" color="0000FF">Nit</label>
        <label id="7" color="FF9F48">Tight</label>
        <label id="8" color="C0C0C0">Undefined</label>
    </labels>
    <note player="&quot;Seikei&quot;&amp;5RS" label="8" update="1429734930"></note>
    <note player="#23Mattingly" label="5" update="1429734930">Note1</note>
    <note player="#PachnacyBak" label="7" update="1429734930">Note2</note>
    <note player="$attlaz" label="2" update="1429734930">Note3</note>
    <note player="111kakarot" label="1" update="1429734930"></note>
    <note player="111PO111" label="2" update="1429734930"></note>
</notes>
```

The rules are: If a line with the same player id is already exist, than I'd like replace only the label number with the value from the newer file, and if there is any note after the update tag in the older file, I'd like to keep that note in the merged output file, but change the label number if it is different in the newer file. Secondly: If there is a line in the newer file that has no match in the older file by player id, then I would like to copy that whole line in the merged output file. The samples are above.

Comment: In what way are these XML files invalid?

Comment: They have multiple tags/values in one line, isn't that invalid?

Comment: This depends a lot on what language you are using, but the basic idea is to parse the XML into an object graph and then traverse the object graphs and apply any specific merging logic that you man have.

Comment: No, you could put the whole thing on one line and it would be perfectly valid. (if you really want to know then here is the section on white space in the XML spec http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space)